# How to check for correlation between 5 classes (Likert ratings) and continous variable?

Tags: classification, correlation

Apologies if the question seems basic or technical terms are used incorrectly, but I am not very experienced in statistics.

I have collected data concerning different properties of objects, let's say animals, that are classified into 5 classes. The classes are equidistant and ordered Likert ratings 1-5 (for example representing weight, so 1 = low weight, 5 = high weight). Each object (animal) belongs to a class 1-5, and the properties are all numerical and continous. So the data looks something like this:

| Animal (unique ID) | Class | Property1 | Property2 | Property3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fish | 1 | 0.5 | 2 | 2.2 | ... |
| Cat | 3 | 0.2 | 1 | 1.3 | ... |
| Horse | 4 | 1.2 | 4 | 3 | ... |
| Dog | 3 | 0.8 | 2.5 | 1 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

How do I test whether there is a correlation between the classification into the 5 classes and a certain property? For example, if property 1 was volume, then surely low volume would correlate to lower classes/lower weight, and high volume would correlate to higher classes/higher weight.

What I'm actually trying to do is to build a program that analyses these objects, and then uses their properties to predict a class. So I need to compare the properties to find out which work best as class predictors.

I could obviously just get the averages for each property per class and then compare, to see if there is a trend from 1-5, but that doesn't seem statistically sound. Especially if I need to compare the "degree of correlation" with the classes for different properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n = 50$ subjects, suppose you have Likert variable `x1` and numerical variable `x2` with a positive association between categorical values of `x1` and values `x2`. Perhaps they are
somewhat similar to the fictitious variables sampled in R and summarized below:

```
summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   3.000   3.000   3.356   4.000   5.000 
summary(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  9.919  10.301  10.409  10.408  10.525  10.892
```

The plot below shows a clear positive association:

```
plot(x1,x2, pch=20)
```

[image]

You could find the Pearson correlation $r = 0.756$ between
the two variables.

```
cor(x1,x2)
[1]  0.7562872
```

Because `x1` is ordinal categorical and because the relationship may not be exactly linear, it may make more sense
to look at Spearman correlation $r_S = 0.750,$ which is the Pearson correlation of the ranks of the two variables.

```
cor(x1,x2, meth="s")
[1] 0.7496384
cor(rank(x1), rank(x2))
[1] 0.7496384
```

Once you see that there are associations among some of your variables, you can explore their consequences using various kinds of regression.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are very straightforward, and there are no problems with what you envision.  While correlation can be used to understand the informativeness of each property feature in terms of linear association (covariance) with class, regression is better since it can actually determine what property features are the most optimal predictors of class.

Obviously, you're supposed to have, in terms of sampling, a lot of values for property1, e.g. $n=30$ for fish in class 1, $n=30$ for cats in class 2, and $n=30$ for horses, plus a lot of values for the other two classes of mammals. In other words, you need sampling variation based on measurements of all the property features from many different animals in the same class.

Then, you can easily determine correlation between class and each property, since class is already ordinal, since it's in the Likert scale with a gradient-based definition --> lower is low weight, higher is high weight.  Linear regression and polytomous (polychotomous) logistic regression are easy classifiers to use as well.  Correlation is not really used for class prediction, at least not nearly as much as various regression models are used.

Once you can apply logistic regression or linear (it would have to be multivariate normal regression), you can then branch out to classification analysis using by K-nearest neighbor (KNN), naive Bayes classifier (NBC), discriminant analysis (LDA), quadratic discriminant analysis (QDA), Fisher discriminant analysis (FDA), decision tree classification (DTC), supervised random forests (SRF), learning vector quantization (LVQ), gradient ascent support vector machines (SVMGA), least squares support vector machines (SVMLS), supervised artificial neural networks (SANN), kernel regression (KREG), particle swarm optimization, supervised neural gas (SNG), and mixture of experts (MOE).